# How do you load jsTree using a variable for data

Tags: jstree

I have an ajax call to a wcf module that returns a menu tree in this format.  (truncated)

```
    { "data" : [
          {
          "data" : "Home", 
          "attr" : {"webpageid" : "1", "url"     : "/Intranet/index.html", "appcode" : "Intranet Home", "parent"  : "0", "enabled" : "1", "visible" : "1", "target"  : "_self     ", "order"   : "0", "title"   : "Home", "itmname" : "index", "submenuclass" : "", "htmlid" : "homenav", "opennewtab" : "true", "externalsite" : "0"},
          "children" :[
                        {
                        "data" : "Site Administration", 
                        "attr" : {"webpageid" : "64", "url"     : "", "appcode" : "Mgmt/S0001", "parent"  : "1", "enabled" : "1", "visible" : "1", "target"  : "_self     ", "order"   : "1", "title"   : "Site Administration", "itmname" : "SiteAdmin", "submenuclass" : "", "htmlid" : "", "opennewtab" : "false", "externalsite" : "0"},
                        "children" :[
                        {
                        "data" : "Add Web Page", 
                        "attr" : {"webpageid" : "65", "url"     : "/Intranet/admin/mgmt/addwebpage.html", "appcode" : "Mgmt/S0002", "parent"  : "64", "enabled" : "1", "visible" : "1", "target"  : "_self     ", "order"   : "1", "title"   : "Add Web Page", "itmname" : "AddPage", "submenuclass" : "", "htmlid" : "", "opennewtab" : "false", "externalsite" : "0"} 
                        }
                      ]
          }
        ]
```

}, ... more data ...
]}

here is the call back function from my ajax call:

```
function fSucc(data) {
    $(function () {
        $('#webpagetree').jstree({
            "json_data": (function () { return data; })(),
            "ui": { "select_limit": 1 },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "themeroller", "dnd", "crrm"]
        }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
            alert(jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "jstree").id)
        });
    });
}
```

but it doesn't create or load an instance of the jsTree.

instead I get the error "Neither data nor ajax settings supplied."
I've also tried putting the data into a global variable, then returning that.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just want

```
$('#webpagetree').jstree({
    "json_data": data,
...
```

in your fSucc function?

Comment: Iwould have thought so, but I tried that and it didn't work.  I'm using 1.5.2.  I wonder if thats the problem?

Comment: Hmm, OK.  I would try three things: 1. hard code the data in your function to check its working as expected. 2. Use console.log to check the value of `data` to check it is as expected.  3: try outputting a simple version of data from your ajax, eg a copy of working json from jstree docs).

Answer (score 1):

Adding an eval() around the data will work.

```
"json_data": { "data" : eval(data) },
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well by passing the variable containing the json in the function **eval()** :

```
$('#webpagetree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': eval(myJson)
    }
});
```